# Java return value, object references

Tags: java, return-value, scope, return-type

I have read Jon Skeet's [[excellent] article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html) about passing values in Java and seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/40523#40523) on the same topic. I believe I understand them but what I am still 
wondering about is return values.

When an object is returned (as from a getter) then later altered in it's original scope (where it was gotten from) is the object reference owned by the variable to which the getter's return value was assigned altered? Boy that was a mouthful..
To borrow an example:

```
public class Dog {

    String dog ;

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.dog;
    }

    public Dog(String dog)
    {
        this.dog = dog;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.dog = name;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Dog myDog = new Dog("Rover");
        String dogName = myDog.getName();
        myDog.setName("Max");
        System.out.println(dogName);
    }
}
```

Does that print **Rover** or **Max**?

**UPDATE**
Does print Rover.

The answers to my original question were great but Richard Tingle added a lot of useful information in the comments below so I thought I'd provide my test class for posterity.

```
public class Foo {
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayList;

    public Foo() {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        arrayList.add(1);
        arrayList.add(2);
        arrayList.add(3);

    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getArrayList() {
        return arrayList;
    }

    public void addToArrayList(int item) {
        arrayList.add(item);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = foo.getArrayList();
        ArrayList<Integer> cloneList = (ArrayList<Integer>)foo.getArrayList().clone();
        System.out.println(arrayList.contains(4));
        System.out.println(cloneList.contains(4));
        foo.addToArrayList(4);
        System.out.println(arrayList.contains(4));
        System.out.println(cloneList.contains(4));
}
```

Output is `false`, `false`, `true`, `false`

Comment: How about running that code and see what happens?

Comment: `String` is anyway immutable. So `dogName` would still be `Rover`

Comment: NOW I feel dumb. Thank you :)

Comment: I don't think this question should be upvoted, specially when OP can **easily** run the code and see the result.

Comment: It will be Rover because in the Dog object you just changed the reference from one String object to another, but the dogName still references the old object. BTW, you should run the code yourself.

Comment: If I under stand, you want know if the string dogName will change it's value because you've changed the name property on the Dog object you got the dogName from. In short, no.

Comment: That is what I thought but thank you all for reminding me I have a compiler. Valuable lesson learned :)

Comment: Its worth noting this would be different if you retrieved an internal object from `Dog` and then modified the internal state of that object

Comment: @RichardTingle By that you mean that if the name were instead a `List` or perhaps another `Dog` that the value **would** be altered?

Comment: @BrassApparatus To an extent. Strings are immutable so you can't change their internal state. But if you had a string where you could change the internal state, lets call it `MutableString` and you called `myDog.getMutableName().setLetter(2,"Z")` then the dogs internal string would be "RoZer". `String temp=myDog.getMutableName(); temp="does nothing";` would still not effect the dogs internal string though

Comment: @RichardTingle Likewise, a reference to member `ArrayList` who's collection was altered would be altered as well?

Comment: @BrassApparatus If you retrieve the `arrayList` and then add objects to it this would affect the `ArrayList` within `Dog`. If you retrieve the `arrayList` and set your variable to a completely different `ArrayList` then this won't affect the arrayList within `Dog` (because its a different `ArrayList`)

Comment: @RichardTingle And simmilarily, if you retrieve the `ArrayList` and alter the version **within** `Dog` the version you retrieved will be altered?

Comment: @BrassApparatus Indeed, the general rule is if you change a variable to point to a different object only that variable is changed (like changing the address in your address book), this always involves an `=` and may involve a `new` (but may not and the new is hidden with strings) . On the other hand if you use a method on an object (like sending a parcel to to house to which you have an address) then everywhere that object is visible will see the change (this always involves a `.` to a method that is a setter (or otherwise changes the object))

Comment: @RichardTingle THAT is integral to the spirit of my question and should definitley be an answer!

Comment: @BrassApparatus I've tried to combine my comments into an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23384940/2187042)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been stated by many answers "Rover" will be printed because you have changed the actual string inside `dog`. You haven't changed the String itself (which you can't do as Strings are immutable, aka unchangeable).

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Dog myDog = new Dog("Rover"); //myDog contains STRING1 ("Rover")
    String dogName = myDog.getName(); //dogName is set to refer to STRING1 ("Rover")
    myDog.setName("Max"); //myDog name set to STRING2 ("Max") (STRING1 unaffected)
    System.out.println(dogName); //dogName still refers to STRING1 ("Rover"), "rover" printed
}
```

## More general concept

This may give the impression that once you retrieve an internal object from another object using a getter it is entirely separate and you can change it as you see fit. This isn't always the case. Strings are immutable so you can't change their internal state. But if you accessed an object that was mutable (aka could be changed) and changed *its* internal state outside the `Dog` object then it would still affect the internal state of the `Dog` object. I will use an `ArrayList` to show this concept

```
public class Dog {

    public ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    public void setNames(ArrayList<String> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         Dog dog=new Dog();
         dog.getNames().add("Rover");

         ArrayList<String> someArrayList=dog.getNames();
         someArrayList.add("Rex");

         System.out.println(dog.getNames().contains("Rex")); //prints true. dog's internal state effected from afar

         someArrayList=new ArrayList<String>(); //change someArrayList to refer to a whole new ArrayList
         someArrayList.add("bad");

         System.out.println(dog.getNames().contains("bad")); //prints false, someArrayList now points to a different ArrayList to the one internal to dog

    }

}
```

As you can see if you retrieve the arrayList and then add objects to it this would affect the ArrayList within Dog. If you retrieve the arrayList and set your variable to a completely different ArrayList then this won't affect the arrayList within Dog (because its a different ArrayList). Think of objects as being "no where in particular" and variables being addressed to those objects.

So an analogy; you (a `Dog` object) have an address book of houses you care about (other objects). You can change your address book to point to a different house, no one else will care about that. But if you post a letter to a house saying "paint the door green" everyone else with an address to that house will notice.

The general rule is if you change a variable to point to a different object only that variable is changed (like changing the address in your address book), this always involves an `=` and may involve a `new` (but may not and the new is hidden with strings) . On the other hand if you use a method on an object (like sending a parcel to a house to which you have an address) then everywhere that object is visible will see the change (this always involves a `.` to a method that is a setter (or otherwise changes the object, like `add`))

Answer (score 6):

It will print Rover once.

Reason :

```
 public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.dog = name;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Dog myDog = new Dog("Rover");
        String dogName = myDog.getName(); // here you are setting dogName to rover
        myDog.setName("Max");             // Here you are setting the String field of a Dog object to "Max" (just reassigning the reference and making it point to Max"
        System.out.println(dogName); // DogName is still Rover.
  // do  dogName = myDog.getName(); and print it.. And see what happens :)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> Does that print Rover or Max?

It will print `Rover`.

Because, you already retrieved the value from that `Dog` object. Later alternation to `Dog` object `myDog`, won't affect the value of variable `dogName`

> When an object is returned (as from a getter) then later altered in
>   it's original scope (where it was gotten from) is the object reference
>   owned by the variable to which the getter's return value was assigned
>   altered?

No, it won't alter the reference you assigned. Because you already retrieved the value.

Answer (score 0):

It will be Rover because in the Dog object you just changed the reference from one String object ("Rover") to another ("Max"), but the dogName still references "Rover". BTW, you should run the code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

By doing this:

```
String dogName = myDog.getName();
```

you are creating a new String object containing "Rover" that is not referencing the attribute dog in the object myDog: they are completely independent.
So when you modify the dog value of myDog, this change won't affect the variable "dogName"